# VBA - Loop Through All Sheets And Exclude One

Tags: vba, excel

I need to perform the exact same task on all the sheets in the workbook except for one, I have the below code but I get the following error:

> End If without Block If

```
    Sub Servers3_DeleteIrrelevantColumns()

    'Initialize variables
    Dim currentColumn As Integer
    Dim columnHeading As String
    Dim wrkSht As Worksheet

    'Rename headers on all sheets if matched

        If wrkSht.Name <> "New Servers" Then
    For Each wrkSht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

            wrkSht.Cells(1, 1).EntireRow.Replace What:="*ServerName*", Replacement:="Server Name", Lookat:=xlWhole

            For currentColumn = wrkSht.UsedRange.Columns.Count To 1 Step -1

                columnHeading = wrkSht.UsedRange.Cells(1, currentColumn).Value

                'Check whether to keep column
                Select Case columnHeading

                    Case "Server Name"

                    'Do nothing

                    Case Else

                    wrkSht.Columns(currentColumn).Delete

                End Select

            Next

        End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You are missing a `Next` for the first `For Each` loop (directly after the `Next` and before the `End If`).

Comment: `For Each wrkSht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets` you do not have `End For`

Comment: Your `If wrkSht.Name <> "New Servers" Then` condition should be in your `For Each wrkSht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets` loop as outside of that loop, `wrkSht` is just a `Worksheet` object and isn't pointing to a worksheet

Comment: @Zac is correct, plus the missing `next` as indicated by @peh. You need the `if sheet<>"name" then` after `for each sh` and `end if` before `next sh`

Comment: Thank you so much all of you :) I amended the code above too as it is working now :)

Comment: The question after last edit doesn't make sense - there's no error, so the question should be deleted or the edit rolled back.

Comment: @EitelDagnin Instead of changing your question to the solution, it is probably better to leave the question in its original state and post your solution as an answer. Also you can accept your own answer as solution after a while (I think one day).

Comment: Apologies, I will "undo" the changes and post the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the working solution to my quesiton:

```
Sub Servers3_DeleteIrrelevantColumns()

    'Initialize variables
    Dim currentColumn As Integer
    Dim columnHeading As String
    Dim wrkSht As Worksheet

    'Rename headers on all sheets if matched

    For Each wrkSht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

        If wrkSht.Name <> "New Servers" Then

            wrkSht.Cells(1, 1).EntireRow.Replace What:="*ServerName*", Replacement:="Server Name", Lookat:=xlWhole

            For currentColumn = wrkSht.UsedRange.Columns.Count To 1 Step -1

                columnHeading = wrkSht.UsedRange.Cells(1, currentColumn).Value

                'Check whether to keep column
                Select Case columnHeading

                    Case "Server Name"

                    'Do nothing

                    Case Else

                    wrkSht.Columns(currentColumn).Delete

                End Select

            Next

        End If

    Next wrkSht

End Sub
```