# Copy the element throughout the whole workbook with exclusion some sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to copy the element throughout the whole workbook, keeping one sheet excluded (the very 1st one).

Following the query here:
[Copy the element throughout a whole workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59325578/copy-the-element-throughout-a-whole-workbook)

and the advice here:

[VBA - Loop Through All Sheets And Exclude One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50022699/vba-loop-through-all-sheets-and-exclude-one)

I prepared the code as per below:

```
 Sub asbuiltcopy()

 Dim Ws As Worksheet, ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, s As Shape

 Set ws1 = Worksheets("Frontsheet")      'sheet containing original textbox
 Set ws2 = Worksheets("Readme")
 Set s = ws1.Shapes("AsBuiltBox")     'name of original textbox

 Application.ScreenUpdating = False

 For Each Ws In Worksheets
   If Ws.Name <> ws1.Name Then
    s.Copy
    Ws.Paste
    Ws.Shapes(Ws.Shapes.Count).Top = s.Top
    Ws.Shapes(Ws.Shapes.Count).Left = s.Left
   End If
   If Ws.Name <> ws2.Name Then
    s.Delete
  End If
 Next Ws

Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

But the debugger says, that an object is required.

I changed my code slightly:

```
 Sub asbuiltcopy()

 Dim Ws As Worksheet, ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, s As Shape

 Set ws1 = Worksheets("Frontsheet")      'sheet containing original textbox
 Set ws2 = Worksheets("Readme")
 Set s = ws1.Shapes("AsBuiltBox")     'name of original textbox

 Application.ScreenUpdating = False

 For Each Ws In Worksheets
 If Ws.Name <> ws1.Name Then
    s.Copy
    Ws.Paste
    Ws.Shapes(Ws.Shapes.Count).Top = s.Top
    Ws.Shapes(Ws.Shapes.Count).Left = s.Left
 End If

 Next Ws

 Application.ScreenUpdating = True

 With ws2
 s.Delete
 End With

End Sub
```

But in this case, I am losing the stamp on my 2nd sheet instead of the first one, which I want to exclude.

The last attempt to the code was:

```
 Sub Asbuiltcopy()

 Dim Ws As Worksheet, ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, s As Shape

 Set ws1 = Worksheets("Frontsheet")      'sheet containing original textbox
 Set ws2 = Worksheets("Readme")
 Set s = ws1.Shapes("AsBuiltBox")     'name of original textbox

 ws2.Hidden = True

 Application.ScreenUpdating = False

 For Each Ws In Worksheets
  If Ws.Name <> ws1.Name Then
    s.Copy
    Ws.Paste
    Ws.Shapes(Ws.Shapes.Count).Top = s.Top
    Ws.Shapes(Ws.Shapes.Count).Left = s.Left
 End If
 Next Ws

 Application.ScreenUpdating = True

 Call AsReadmeremove

 ws2.Hidden = False

 End Sub
```

But now I am getting:

**Compile error:
Method or data member not found** - pointing the `ws2.Hidden = True` line.

What can I do to make the element gone only on the very first sheet instead of on 2nd one?

Comment: Side note - please do not use the "excel-vba" tag :-)

Comment: why not? is this tag going to be closed?

Comment: Well... it's supposed to be closed, but I have little hope that actually will happen. But the description says "This tag is pending removal" - i.e. don't use :-)

Comment: OK, anyway the ws1 dodn't help. The result is exactly the same mate

Comment: You're not even using the `With` block, so `s.Delete` should do exactly what you want.

Comment: It's a way to get rid the element on the sheet which I don't want. Is there any other way to exclude this sheet?

Comment: Your code is doing exactly that... `If ws.Name <> ws1.Name`.

Comment: Yes I know, but If I put If ws.Name <> ws2.Name  it asks me about the element, brobably because I put it before Next ws.

Comment: Your first code snippet didn't work because you deleted the shape within the loop, so then trying to copy it on the next iteration will fail... But this all gets back to the point of why are you deleting the shape?

Comment: Because I thought that it's one of the way to exclude the worksheet. I am keen to learn another way.

Comment: The way you have it in the second snippet is right, as long as you remove the `With ws2`, `s.Delete`, and `End With`.