# VBA Excel copy the element throughout a whole workbook when the sheet is hidden

Tags: excel, vba

Good afternoon,

I would like to copy the textbox throughout the whole workbook, but I want to exclude one sheet at once.
The original answer is here:

[Copy the element throughout a whole workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59325578/copy-the-element-throughout-a-whole-workbook)

but now, even if I include the unwanted sheet I am getting an error:
**The item with the specified name wasn't found.**

with the debugger showing:

```
    Set s = ws1.Shapes("AsBuiltBox")
```

[image]

My full code looks like this, but I switched off the lines responsible for hiding the sheet, which I don't want because it didn't work.

```
 Sub Asbuiltstamp()
 Dim myDocument As Worksheet
 Set myDocument = Worksheets(2)
  With myDocument.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 725, 60, 200, 100)
 .Name = "AsBuiltBox"
  With .TextFrame
     .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
     With .Characters
        .Text = "Openreach As-Built"
        .Font.ColorIndex = 3
        .Font.Size = 36
        .Font.Bold = True
     End With
  End With
  .Rotation = 35
  .Fill.Visible = False
 End With
 End Sub


    Sub Asbuiltcopy()

    Dim Ws As Worksheet, ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, s As Shape

 Set ws1 = Worksheets("Readme")      'sheet containing original textbox
 'Set ws2 = Worksheets("Readme")
 Set s = ws1.Shapes("AsBuiltBox")     'name of original textbox

 'ws2.Hidden = True

 Application.ScreenUpdating = False

 For Each Ws In Worksheets
    'Ws.Unprotect "Secret"
   If Ws.Name <> ws1.Name Then
    s.Copy
    Ws.Paste
    Ws.Shapes(Ws.Shapes.Count).Top = s.Top
    Ws.Shapes(Ws.Shapes.Count).Left = s.Left
 End If
 Next Ws

 Application.ScreenUpdating = True

 Call AsReadmeremove

 'ws2.Hidden = False

 End Sub
```

I also tried to solve this problem here:

[Copy the element throughout the whole workbook with exclusion some sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60510387/copy-the-element-throughout-the-whole-workbook-with-exclusion-some-sheets)

Is there any way to make it running?

Comment: At which line does the error appear? Here: `Set s = ws1.Shapes("AsBuiltBox")`? If yes, there is not such a shape on that specific worksheet. If not, please specify where the error appears. Anyhow, an error message must always be related to the code line where it appears. This saves our time and not let us losing our helping enthusiasm...

Comment: I think the error is self explanatory: the sheet doesn't have a shape with that name. You can check if the sheet has that shape and then proceed accordingly

Comment: I have added another macro responsible for creating the textbox.